# PYTHON DATAFRAME conditional group

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe table which looks like the following

[image]

How do I reconstruct this table and sum the rows where length is under 2. so the output df looks like the following

[image]

please any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

thanks
Shei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new column to indicate the length group:

```
df['len_group'] = df['length'].astype(str)
df.loc[df['length']<=2, 'len_group'] = '<=2'
```

Then groupby on the new column:

```
df.groupby('len_group')
```

Test Case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'length':[1,2,3,4,5], 'val':[2,3,4,5,6]})

length  val
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5
4   5   6
```

```
df['len_group'] = df['length'].astype(str)
df.loc[df['length']<=2, 'len_group'] = '<=2'
df_result = df.groupby('len_group')[['val']].sum()

    
len_group   val
3         4
4         5
5         6
<=2       5
```

Comment: thanks Z, I have the new column included but the return df is still showing all the values and not grouping/ summing the rows where length is under 2k,

Comment: did you do the groupby step? And groupby on the new column?

Comment: yes I did and when I print the df again, it still shows all the vals

Comment: maybe you forgot to assign the values to the old dataframe. It is not a change done in place. See my updated test case.

Comment: let me try it, In my case, I don't have a single val column to sum. I have multiple columns?

Comment: replace `[['val']]` with `[['val1', 'val2']]` in groupby for multiple columns